# Numpy: Using a matrix as indices for another matrix to create a tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

how would the following code work?

```
k = np.array([[ 0.,          0.07142857,  0.14285714],
              [ 0.21428571,  0.28571429,  0.35714286],
              [ 0.42857143,  0.5,         0.57142857],
              [ 0.64285714,  0.71428571,  0.78571429],
              [ 0.85714286,  0.92857143,  1.        ]])
y = np.array([[0, 3, 1, 2],
              [2, 1, 0, 3]])
b = k[y]
```

The shapes are:

> > > k shape: (5, 3)
> > >
> > > y shape: (2, 4)
> > >
> > > b shape: (2, 4, 3)

Why would a numpy matrix accept another matrix as its index and how would k find the correct output? Why is a tensor produced instead?

The output of b is

```
  [[[ 0.          0.07142857  0.14285714]
  [ 0.64285714  0.71428571  0.78571429]
  [ 0.21428571  0.28571429  0.35714286]
  [ 0.42857143  0.5         0.57142857]]

 [[ 0.42857143  0.5         0.57142857]
  [ 0.21428571  0.28571429  0.35714286]
  [ 0.          0.07142857  0.14285714]
  [ 0.64285714  0.71428571  0.78571429]]]
```

Comment: With `k[y]` you are just indexing into the first axis with it. Since, `k` is `2D`, you are selecting the rows from it. Also, since, `y` is `2D`, we would have those rows arranged as `2D` and thus the resultant array as `3D`.

Comment: To generalise, how would this work for a matrix k of shape (M,N), and a matrix y of shape (A,B)? What are the constraints to ensure the indexing will work?

Comment: That's valid with `k` and `y` being 2D array of any lengths. Constraints : Keep the elements in y `< k.shape[0]` and `>=0`.

Comment: by y<k.shape[0], do you mean all the individual integers in the shape of y (in this case, 2 and 4), to be lesser than k.shape[0] (in this case 5)?

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment. So, the shape of `y` doesn't matter in the constraints, just the elements in `y` must be greater than or equal to zero and lesser than k.shape[0], i.e. number of rows in `k`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **[integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).**

> Integer array indexing allows selection of arbitrary items in the
>   array based on their N-dimensional index. Each integer array
>   represents a number of indexes into that dimension.

Example -

```
x = array([[ 0,  1,  2],
            [ 3,  4,  5],
            [ 6,  7,  8],
            [ 9, 10, 11]])
rows = np.array([[0, 0],
                  [3, 3]], dtype=np.intp)
columns = np.array([[0, 2],
                     [0, 2]], dtype=np.intp)
x[rows, columns]
```

Output -

```
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

In this case as you can see we are selecting the corner elements by giving the "coordinates" of the elements. And if you try just giving a single 2d 
matrix it'll just evaluate it like -

```
x[rows]
```

Output -

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 0,  1,  2]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

Comment: Is there a way to quickly know what the shape of the output will be given the shapes of the rows/columns matrix and the shape of x?

Comment: I won't say its a quick way, but if you are trying to access a n-dimentional array with a single k dimensional array where k <= n. I think the resulting array will be (k+1) dimensional.

Comment: Is it alright if I use this idea, say k is of shape (M,N), and y is of shape (A,B), so A will determine how many rows of matrices there should be so we know the output matrix will be (A, ?  , ?), then B will select the rows of K to produce B rows of (1,N), which gives a (B,N) matrix in total. Since there are A number of matrices in total, we know A number of (B,N) matrices will give a tensor of (A,B,N). Is this correct?

Comment: I see...However I still don't get how this idea would fit in if I were to account for columns. x[row] is still understandable but if it were x[row, column], it would be more confusing. Why would the coordinates be selected in a diagonal fashion?

Comment: you mean parallel selection? Btw I don't think there is a need to generalize, it'd become more confusing if you have input array of higher dimensions. Its about which element/row you want to access and tweak it accordingly.

Comment: @kwotsin In general, if you think if you try to index using just rows you are going 1 dimension deep in the original array, the more you give the more deeper you go. And the more deeper you go, the more you'll be reducing the dimension of the output array.

Comment: Oh..I think I got it. Basically the individual element of row and column matrices at the same position in the matrices (e.g. position [0,1] in row is 0, while position [0,1] in column is 2, so together they give [0,2]) give a combined index (like [0,2]), which in turns select the position in the 2D matrix.

Comment: Hmm I thought it this way... The first matrix "rows" gives you the index of the outermost dimension and then corresponding element in the "column" matrix gives you the index of exact element. For eg. 0 in rows gets you the first row and corresponding element in column, 0 gets you to the 0th value in that row.